# Minecraft server freezing every 1-2 days

Tags: ubuntu

I've been having issues with my servers just freezing (talking VelocityProxy and Minecraft (Paper)). I think that this is due to the IPv6 interface restarting. It looks like Velocity listens on IPv6, and around the error time the IPv6 interface restarts. This issue occurs every 1-2 days, randomly.

So the logs for around that time, not very useful but:

- Velocity Proxy: https://pastebin.com/dhmpTtEV
- MC Server: https://pastebin.com/Xk41cyMw
- /var/logs/syslog: https://pastebin.com/54qebKKm
- /var/logs/kern.log: https://pastebin.com/NDXZYWga

Note: The MC server and Velocity run one hour behind.

Another thing I have noticed is that this `pterodactyl0: port 3(veth8055ae8) entered blocking state`occurs quite often, pterodactyl is the managing platform I use for the servers.

Server info:

- CPU: Ryzen 2600
- Memory: 16 Gb (2x8) 3000 Mhz
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Minecraft Version: 1.14.4
- Paper Version: git-Paper-226

I have already disabled the firewall in case that was the issue, which it wasn't. Storage, CPU, Memory or temperatures don't appear to be an issue either.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your computer's Ethernet port connected to? A router or modem? Does it have any logs?

Comment: connected to the router directly. They dont show any weird things in the logs. No weird things reported in UniFi (Router is a Unifi USG)